# Count Page Views with Next.js API

Tags: javascript, api, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

i'm newbie in next.js. And i want to count my blog views with next.js and firebase realtime database, I cannot POST any data into Firebase realtime database but this error show up

> API resolved without sending a response for /api/views/test-blog, this may result in stalled requests.

Here is my API code:

```
import db from '@/lib/firebase';

export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const ref = db.ref('views').child(req.query.id);
    const { snapshot } = await ref.transaction((currentViews) => {
      if (currentViews === null) {
        return 1;
      }

      return currentViews + 1;
    });

    return res.status(200).json({
      total: snapshot.val()
    });
  }
};
```

Any Suggestion guys?

Updated: I've add a components with the codes below, in to Page's Layouts:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import useSWR from 'swr';
import format from 'comma-number';

import fetcher from '@/lib/fetcher';

export default function ViewCounter({ slug }) {
  const { data } = useSWR(`/api/views/${slug}`, fetcher);
  const views = data?.total;

  useEffect(() => {
    const registerView = () =>
      fetch(`/api/views/${slug}`, {
        method: 'POST'
      });

    registerView();
  }, [slug]);

  return `${views ? format(views) : '---'} views`;
}
```

And this error show up :

```
Error: child failed: path argument was an invalid path = "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]" –
```

Comment: You probably called it with GET and your return nothing in that case?

Comment: @Danila i didn't call it yet, with the code above i cannot POST any count into the Firebase Realtim database

Comment: If you didn't call it yet how could you know that it does not work?

Comment: I can check it by reload the Firebase realtime database console, it's still NULL

Comment: Let's start again. Have you called your api handler? If NO (you said `i didn't call it yet`) then how do you know it does not work? If YES then how did you call it exactly? You need to post the code which calls it

Comment: oh i'm sorry, misunderstand! i hit `http://localhost:3000/api/views/test-blog` to log a view to the database, but notthing counted and the error show up

Comment: If you just opened it in browser then it is not POST but a GET request, and you have no handling for it therefore there is no response

Comment: oh i see, any suggestion for me?

Comment: how did u fix it?